# Create a new array of objects that have the same key within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this schedules array and I need it to turn into this output. Got any clues?

```
let schedules = [
 {day: 'Sunday', time: '5:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '4:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '12:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Tuesday', time: '1:00 PM'}
]

let output = [
 {day: 'Sunday', time: '5:00 PM'},
 [
  {day: 'Monday', time: '4:00 PM'},
  {day: 'Monday', time: '12:00 PM'}
 ],
 {day: 'Tuesday', time: '1:00 PM'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `reduce()` to create one object and then `map()` to get array of values.

```js
let schedules = [
 {day: 'Sunday', time: '5:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '4:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '12:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Tuesday', time: '1:00 PM'}
]

var obj = schedules.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!r[e.day]) r[e.day] = e
  else r[e.day] = Array.isArray(r[e.day]) ? r[e.day].concat(e) : [r[e.day]].concat(e)
  return r;
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(e => obj[e])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let schedules = [
 {day: 'Sunday', time: '5:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '4:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Monday', time: '12:00 PM'},
 {day: 'Tuesday', time: '1:00 PM'}
];
var temp = {};
schedules.forEach(function(ob){
   temp[ob.day] = temp[ob.day] === undefined ? ob : Array.isArray(temp[ob.day]) ? temp[ob.day].concat([ob]) : [temp[ob.day]].concat([ob]);
})
var output = Object.values(temp);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out! but is there a way to only make monday an array and not the other objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reduce with Object values

```js
let schedules = [{
    day: 'Sunday',
    time: '5:00 PM'
  },
  {
    day: 'Monday',
    time: '4:00 PM'
  },
  {
    day: 'Monday',
    time: '12:00 PM'
  },
  {
    day: 'Monday',
    time: '3:00 PM'
  },
  {
    day: 'Tuesday',
    time: '1:00 PM'
  }
]


var value = schedules.reduce((acc, i) => {
  if (!acc[i.day]) {
    acc[i.day] = i
  } else if (Array.isArray(acc[i.day])) {
    acc[i.day].push(i);
  } else if (typeof acc[i.day] === 'object') {
    acc[i.day] = [acc[i.day]]
    acc[i.day].push(i)
  }

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(...Object.values(value))
```

Comment: @kyangy I think you might like this solution more, it's simpler